# Magic scrolling colours Codepen issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a novice looking to learn some basic js.

I am trying to implement this code https://codepen.io/daveredfern/pen/zBGBJV but can't get it functioning. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

As it stands, the css is loading fine, but when I preview the file locally in my browser, the transitions do not work. Works fine in Codepen so I am not sure what I am doing wrong to implement the js.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>


<div class="panel" data-color="white">
    <div>
      <h1>Magic scrolling colours</h1>
      <p>Scroll to animate the background colour of the body as a full height panel becomes visible.</p>
      <p>I have tried to comment the code, particurly the JavaScript, as much as possible. I hope it's clear to understand.</p>
      <p>If you have any questions my twitter is <a href="https://twitter.com/daveredfern">@daveredfern</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" data-color="violet">
  <h2>Violet panel</h2>
</div>
<div class="panel" data-color="indigo">
  <h2>Indigo panel</h2>
</div>
<div class="panel" data-color="blue">
  <h2>Blue panel</h2>
</div>
<div class="panel" data-color="green">
  <h2>Green panel</h2>
</div>
<div class="panel" data-color="yellow">
  <h2>Yellow panel</h2>
</div>
<div class="panel" data-color="orange">
  <h2>Orange panel</h2>
</div>
<div class="panel" data-color="red">
  <h2>Red panel</h2>
</div>

<script>
    <script>
jQuery(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function() {

  // selectors
  var $window = $(window),
      $body = $('body'),
      $panel = $('.panel');

  // Change 33% earlier than scroll position so colour is there when you arrive.
  var scroll = $window.scrollTop() + ($window.height() / 3);

  $panel.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    // if position is within range of this panel.
    // So position of (position of top of div <= scroll position) && (position of bottom of div > scroll position).
    // Remember we set the scroll to 33% earlier in scroll var.
    if ($this.position().top <= scroll && $this.position().top + $this.height() > scroll) {

      // Remove all classes on body with color-
      $body.removeClass(function (index, css) {
        return (css.match (/(^|\s)color-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
      });

      // Add class of currently active div
      $body.addClass('color-' + $(this).data('color'));
    }
  });

}).scroll();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
/* Setting fade transition and default settings */
body {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

/* panel styles */
.panel {
  /* min height incase content is higher than window height */
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* outline: 10px solid hotpink; */
  /* turn above on to see the edge of panels */
}

/* colours */
.color-violet {
  background-color: #7A4EAB;
}
.color-indigo {
  background-color: #4332CF;
}
.color-blue {
  background-color: #2F8FED;
}
.color-green {
  background-color: #4DCF42;
}
.color-yellow {
  background-color: #FAEB33;
}
.color-orange {
  background-color: #F19031;
}
.color-red {
  background-color: #F2293A;
}

/* styling for demo, can ignore */
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 120%;
  line-height: 1.618;
}
h1, h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
p {
  max-width: 30em;
  margin-bottom: 1.618em;
}
a {
  color: #4332CF;
}
```

Comment: Did you copy the code exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because you haven't imported or installed jQuery in your project. You can use a CDN (amongst other ways) to link or install jQuery in your project.
Just above the first script, add this snippet that adds jQuery to your project.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
```